# why does textarea show old data

Tags: reactjs, class

In my Javascript React code I am running in a strange problem. I made code to show and edit the values of a global javascript object with 2-dim arrays. Everything works fine, except when I try to show the resulting global data, I can only get the old, unedited data in a textarea. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    class DataBox extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    <hr />
                    <div>nr of samples: {_samples.Samples.length}, data object:</div>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">{JSON.stringify(_samples.Samples, null, 4)}</textarea>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }//end class DataBox
</script>
```

The app code uses the `<DataBox />` class. The global data object `_samples` has an array `Samples` with 4 main objects that are displayed on the html page. The `<DataBox />` shows "nr of samples: 4".

When I use the app to delete the 1st main item, the `setstate` call in the app causes also the child `<DataBox />`  to be rendered. This shows correctly: "nr of samples: 3", but the `<textarea />` shows the global data with the 4 samples from before the deletion.

How is it possible that `_samples.Samples` has two different value in two lines of this React class?

Comment: I would use `value` prop for textarea but that would require additional refactoring. If you changed your text area to a `<span>` would the content display correctly?

Comment: I already tested with an alert() and that shows correct updated data. Does a textarea need special code to clear or update its data?

Comment: You can try adding a unique `key` to the textarea as a workaround. When React sees a new key, it forces it to re-render that element: ```<textarea rows="4" cols="50" key={_samples.Samples.length}>{JSON.stringify(_samples.Samples, null, 4)}</textarea>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, `<textarea>` uses a value attribute instead of children for its text.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag

Try it like this:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" value={JSON.stringify(_samples.Samples, null, 4)} />
```

Comment: I was already reading that page, but you were faster :-) Indeed, `textarea` is special as it maintains its own state, like `input` and `select`, as explained by your link.